# WSO2SP throws java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

I've created a siddhi file and moved it to the WSO2SP worker for deployment.

When I check my container logs, I find that the app has been deployed successfully. This is the curl command I'm passing.

```
curl -X POST http://0.0.0.0:7711/IrisPrediction -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{"SLength": 3.3, "SWidth": 3.2, "PLength": 4.2, "PWidth": 4.4}'
```

This is what I can see in the container logs.

```
[2019-07-30 11:20:56,020]  INFO {org.wso2.extension.siddhi.io.http.source.HttpConnectorPortBindingListener} - HTTP source 0.0.0.0:7711 has been started
[2019-07-30 11:20:56,021]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.stream.processor.core.internal.StreamProcessorService} - Siddhi App Iris_Curl deployed successfully
[2019-07-30 11:20:56,025]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.kernel.internal.CarbonStartupHandler} - WSO2 Stream Processor started in 47.445 sec
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to /home/wso2carbon/wso2sp-4.3.0/wso2/worker/logs/heap-dump.hprof ...
Unable to create /home/wso2carbon/wso2sp-4.3.0/wso2/worker/logs/heap-dump.hprof: File exists
```

What is going wrong here? How do I resolve this?

On a side note, I tried doing the same thing with the editor container and it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the siddhi apps you used, seems some of the processing is consuming huge memory.

You can edit the Xms and Xmx in /wso2/worker/bin/carbon.sh file to allocate at least 4Gb.

Also, use the latest SP 4.4.0, as some memory leak issues were fixed in the latest.